# get average from a file list

Tags: python, file, store, average

so previously I created a code that prompts the user to enter 5 different test scores and then to have that list saved to test.txt. the code works wonderful! 
this is my code:

```
scorefile=open('test.txt','w')

for count in range(5):

    print('Please enter test scores')

    score=input('Test score:')

    scorefile.write(str(score)+'%' + '\n')

scorefile.close()
```

BUT now, i encounter a problem. I have the code to read the file. it works great! but when I try to get the average from the list, all I keep getting is 0.0. I've been reading thru my book about python to figure out how to make this work, but Im seriously stuck now. help?
here is my code:

```
scorefile=open('test.txt', 'r')

for line in scorefile:

    print(line, end='')

    score=scorefile

average = sum(score) / 5

print('The test average is', average)

scorefile.close()
```

Comment: Please put your sample code into code blocks. To do so, select your code and press the `{}` button in the toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

This line, `score=scorefile` doesn't do what you think it does. In fact, it doesn't do anything useful at all.

Perhaps you want:

```
with open('test.txt') as scorefile:
    scores = [int(line.replace('%','')) for line in scorefile]
    average = sum(scores) / len(scores)
```

Answer (score 0):

`score=scorefile` just assigns the file descriptor to `score`. It does not actually read the contents and assign them to the `score` variable as you expected.

You need to read the lines in the file, strip the '%' character, convert each line to an float(since they were percentages I am assuming), sum them up and take the average.

Like this:

```
with open('input') as in_file:
    data = in_file.readlines()
average = sum([float(a.strip('%')) for a in data]) / len(data)
print(average)
```

`[float(a.strip('%')) for a in data]` is a short hand notation (also called list comprehension) for doing:

```
a_list = []
for a in data:
    a_list.append(float(a.strip('%')))
```